# UE4 error compiling due to unknown function EditAnywhere

Tags: c++, function, properties, declaration, unreal-engine4

I've been working on an Unreal Engine 4 game using C++ and I've been working on a dash function, however I followed a YouTube tutorial and I noticed that in the video, they use the function "`EditAnywhere`" but when I tried to code that my self, my UE4 says that `EditAnywhere` is unknown function.

Do I need to meet some special requirements to be able to use the "`EditAnywhere`" function?

My Header file sample code:

```
UFUNCTION()
void DoubleJump();

UPROPERTY()
int DoubleJumpCounter;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
float JumpHeight;

UFUNCTION()
void Sprint();

UFUNCTION()
void Walk();

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
float WalkingSpeed;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
float RunningSpeed;

UFUNCTION(EditAnywhere)
void Dash();

UPROPERTY()
bool CanDash;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
float DashStop;

UPROPERTY()
FTimerHandle UnsedHandle;

UFUNCTION()
void StopDashing();

UFUNCTION()
void ResetDash();
```

Here is a picture of the Error message
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not have the `EditAnywhere` for functions!

The [`EditAnywhere` is a property declaration](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Properties/) meant only for the variables.

> Properties are declared using standard C++ variable syntax, preceded by the `UPROPERTY` macro **which defines property metadata and variable specifiers**.
>
> ```
> UPROPERTY([specifier, specifier, ...], [meta(key=value, key=value, ...)])
> Type VariableName;
> ```

---

> Do I need to meet some special requirements to be able to use the
> "`EditAnywhere`" function?

Editing functions does not make any sense, but you can specify the function how to act in different places(Example: blueprint, unreal editor, etc). This has been done via [`UFUNCTION` declaration](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Functions/). See the different declarations in the given link for further read.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `EditAnywhere` with a `UFUNCTION`, only with a `UPROPERTY`. What would it even mean to make a function editable by property windows?

See [Property Specifiers](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Properties/Specifiers/) and [Function Specifiers](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Functions/Specifiers/) for the complete list of supported specifiers.